# Executing a generated sql statement (output)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to execute Query A but I would like to execute Query A using Query B. One way to accomplish this is to spool out the result of Query B to a sql file and run. I would prefer to accomplish this task using PL/SQL.

--Query A

```
delete from
tableA
where
id=4;
```

--Query B

```
select 'delete from' as test from dual
union all
select 'tableA' as test from dual
union all
select 'where' as test from dual
union all
select 'id=4'||';' as test from dual
```

Comment: Why not build the string manually and then execute it using dynamic SQL?

Comment: What is your question? How to write an outer query, using Query B as the subquery, whose result will be a string equal to the statement of Query A? That is trivial - use `LISTAGG(test, chr(10))` - but the trick is the ordering of rows in the four-member `UNION ALL` in Query B. Do you need help with **that**? Is that the reason for your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to `loop` the statement of Query B, and apply `execute immediate` at the end :

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> declare
  v_sql varchar2(4000);
begin

  for c in ( select 'delete from ' as test from dual
              union all
              select 'tableA ' as test from dual
              union all
              select 'where ' as test from dual
              union all
              select 'id=4' as test from dual )   
  loop
    v_sql := v_sql || c.test;
  end loop;            
    dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
    execute immediate v_sql;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like ...

```
begin
  execute immediate 'delete from ta where id = ' || 4 ; 
end;
/
```

Or, if you want to use a procedure:

```
create or replace procedure delete_row ( row_ number )
as
begin
  execute immediate 'delete from ta where id = ' || row_ ; 
end;
/

begin
  delete_row( 4 );
end;
/
```

Dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f20fdd83de6dae4633a33fc7bc62b57c).